# Using facebook graph API to make HTTPS POST request in swift

Tags: swift, facebook-graph-api, post, https

When I use the url below normally on Google Chrome, I am able to create a new facebook test user, I get back a valid json with username and password, and other details back.

https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/2232192233718728/accounts/test-users?installed=true&name=Thomasfsdks&locale=en_US&permissions=read_stream&method=post&access_token=2232192233718728|24q_TtCeh44Z0dUVm7x5pg2U5iQ

However, when I try to do it on swift, it does not seem to work correctly. I am unsure how to make it work.Below is the code in swift.

```
    let appID = "2232192233718728"
    let urlString = "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/" + appID + "/accounts/test-users?"
    let url = URL(string: urlString)!

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let name = "Thomasdasfafada"
    let accessToken = "2232192233718728|24q_TtCeh44Z0dUVm7x5pg2U5iQ"

    let postString = "installed=true&name=" + name + "&locale=en_US&permissions=read_stream&method=post&access_token=" + accessToken

    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)


    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        let responseString = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)

        print("here"+"responseString = \(responseString)")

    }
    task.resume()
```

Comment: Step 1: Go reset your app secret, because it looks like you just exposed it here by showing your app access token, `2232192233718728|24q_TtCeh44Z0dUVm7x5pg2U5iQ`

Comment: _“it does not seem to work correctly”_ - what response did you get from the API?

Comment: `permissions=read_stream` - that permission has been removed ages ago.

Comment: Turns out it was because i was running it in tests, and thus all i had to do was to wait for response to be returned. Cheers for your input! Also yes, it is a dummy app, will delete it soon.